# How to save meta boxes post meta?

Tags: wordpress, meta-boxes

I create this function for metaboxes and to save information, but I can´t save the info and show it into the field.

My Code :

```
function reaction_buttons_meta2() 
{
    global $post;
    $reaction_buttons_off2 = false;
    if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, '_reaction_buttons_off2', true) ) {
        $reaction_buttons_off = true;
    }
    update_post_meta($post->ID, 'reaction_buttons_off2', $_POST['reaction_buttons_off2']);
    $meta=get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['reaction_buttons_off2'], true); 
    ?>
        <input type="text" id="reaction_buttons_off2" name="reaction_buttons_off2" value="<?php echo $meta[reaction_buttons_off2][0]; ?>">
    <?php
}

function reaction_buttons_meta_box2() 
{
    add_meta_box('reaction_buttons2','Reaction Buttons','reaction_buttons_meta2','post','side');
    add_meta_box('reaction_buttons2','Reaction Buttons','reaction_buttons_meta2','page','side');
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'reaction_buttons_meta_box2');
```

I need to put a simple field to store one option and after this show it in the template post.

Comment: **Too many** issues with your code. Really, start again with a good example: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/61041/12615

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never created meta boxes myself, but looking at your code all you do is trying to update meta but you need to add it first with `add_post_meta`.

Check [this](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/04/create-custom-post-meta-boxes-wordpress/) article on How To Create Custom Post Meta Boxes In WordPress.

For your issue, pay attention to **Saving the meta box data** section. As you can see, their function uses `add_post_meta`, `update_post_meta` and `delete_post_meta` functions.